# Wrapper around instance methods with default return value

Tags: python, decorator, return-value, wrapper, default

I have a dozen of (instance) methods that should evaluate only if a condition is satisfied, otherwise return default value which is different for each method:

```
def fun(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.init():
        return ... # <- default value, different for each method
    # method logic
    return ... # some value
```

I managed to make this work with decorators as follows:

```
from functools import partial, wraps


def check_init(caller = None, *, ret = None):
    if caller is None:
        return partial(check_init, ret = ret)
    
    @wraps(caller)
    def _check_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return caller(self, *args, **kwargs) if self.init() else ret
    return _check_init


class Test:
    num: int = 2

    def init(self) -> bool:
        return self.num < 5

    @check_num(ret = 'Cannot show number')
    def show(self) -> str:
        return 'Number is %d' % self.num


x = Test()

print(x.show()) # "Number is 2"

x.num = 4
print(x.show()) # "Number is 4"

x.num = 6
print(x.show()) # "Cannot show number"
```

Two questions:

- Since the described logic is related only to the `Test` instance methods, how can I put the whole `def check_init()` block inside the `Test` class? When it is outside the class I cannot type-hint `self` with `Test` or `Self`.
- Is there a better (more Pythonic) way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Preferably with method decorators..

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to define a decorator inside a class (nor would I recommend it), instead you can type `self` by using a forward reference. A forward reference is a string of the desired type's name that can be used before the type itself is defined.

```py
def check_init(caller=None, *, ret=None):
    if caller is None:
        return partial(check_init, ret=ret)

    @wraps(caller)
    def _check_init(self: "Test", *args, **kwargs):
        return caller(self, *args, **kwargs) if self.init() else ret
    return _check_init


class Test:
    # ...
```

2. Is there a better way? Not that I can think of. If you need to use these decorators across in a variety of class type, it might be wise to make a mixing class that defines your checking (`self.init()`) interface.